# How to set id attribute to table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a table with my id to my table with javascript, I am using `setAttribute` but it is not work, could you please help me?

```
var table = $('<table><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Position</th><th>Note</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table>').addClass('table table-bordered table-hover search-table table-striped');
table.setAttribute("id", "myid");
$('#content').html(table);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `table` is a jQuery object, you need to use [`.attr(attributeName, value)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2)

```
table.attr("id", "myid");
```